# How to automatically add user profile data to contact form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I have website running in Wordpress where users can fill in the contact form that sends email to me. Right now users have to fill in their address, phone number etc. every time they want to contact me. I need to create a contact form that includes user profile data(name, address, phonenumber etc.) automatically.

Is there any specific plugin for this kind of task, or can I modify my existing Contact Form 7 plugin to prefill some fields automatically from contact profile?

Comment: Try this plugin :- [contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/)

Answer (score 5):

Good news, everyone! According to [doc page](http://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/)now you can set default values for your form fields using some data from user account.

Here is a sample from my form:

```
<p>Your name [text client-name default:user_display_name]</p>
```

Available fields at the moment are: *user_email*, *user_url*, *user_first_name*, *user_last_name*, *user_nickname* and *user_display_name*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-registration-contact-form-7/

We have created same like one add on for contact from 7 in which you can convert contact from 7 into registration form or signup form for WordPress user.

By using this plugin you can create registration form by which registered user will be register as a subscriber role in WordPress.

You just need to add plugin and select fields for username and email ID from created fields. In order to use this plugin, make sure your Contact Form 7 is activated.